# Zend Adapter Transaction Rollback Failed MSSQL

Tags: zend-framework, rollback

I have this odd error, i use MSSQL 2008 R2 and ZendFw 1.12

---

First.. the rollback didn’t fail inside try..

```
   // Zend_DB_Table Adapter
   $adapter = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();

   // Start Transaction
   $adapter->beginTransaction();

   try {
          $adapter->rollBack();
          return (int) 1;
   } catch (Exception $e) {
          throw new Api_Exception($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode(), $e);
   }
```

---

But.. the rollback failed inside catch..

Yes i deliberately create error on try bellow to make it goes inside catch..

```
   // Zend_DB_Table Adapter
   $adapter = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();

   // Start Transaction
   $adapter->beginTransaction();

   try {
          return (int) A;
   } catch (Exception $e) {
          $adapter->rollBack();
          throw new Api_Exception($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode(), $e);
   }
```

---

It returns.. `Zend_Db_Adapter_Sqlsrv_Exception: A transaction must be started by calling sqlsrv_begin_transaction before calling sqlsrv_commit or sqlsrv_rollback.`

Any clue please?

Answer (score 0):

hi go and see this link [Rollback in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18588471/rollback-in-sql)

you can use safe and easy code for run 100% (run all line of query) or no run any off them

```
|query 1| = like insert into or select or ...
|count of lines| = number off query

DECLARE @rowcount int  set @rowcount = 0 ; 
BEGIN TRANSACTION [Tran1]
BEGIN TRY 
 <Query 1> ; set @rowcount = (@rowcount + @@ROWCOUNT); 
 <Query 2> ; set @rowcount = (@rowcount + @@ROWCOUNT); 
...
IF @rowcount =  <count of lines>
  COMMIT TRANSACTION[Tran1]
ELSE
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION[Tran1]
END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION[Tran1]
END CATCH
```

for example this code run 2 insert into line query but or run all of him or no run anything and ROLLBACK

```
DECLARE @rowcount int  set @rowcount = 0 ; 
BEGIN TRANSACTION [Tran1]
BEGIN TRY 
 insert into [database].[dbo].[tbl1] (fld1) values('1') ;
    set @rowcount = (@rowcount + @@ROWCOUNT); 
 insert into [database].[dbo].[tbl2] (fld1) values('2') ;
    set @rowcount = (@rowcount + @@ROWCOUNT); 

IF @rowcount =  2
  COMMIT TRANSACTION[Tran1]
ELSE
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION[Tran1]
END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION[Tran1]
END CATCH
```