# Rollback in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following query:

```
use valid
begin transaction t1
go
delete from dbo.do
rollback transaction t1
go
```

With rollback I want to undo the delete operation. Do not get any results, what is wrong?

Comment: Define "any results", unless you use the OUTPUT clause you don't get a result set from DELETE.

Comment: @user2645263 what kind of output you are expecting ??

Answer (score 2):

Try without the "go" after begin transaction.

Comment: It's a batch separator used by client tools (like SSMS) to break the entire script up into batches. I don't think it has anything to do with Transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems ok in the first look and it should work without any issue. I've tried similar sample code as shown below and it works fine:

```
  use [replocal]
  begin transaction t1
  go 
  delete from dbo.ftpfilelog
  rollback transaction t1
  go
  select * from dbo.ftpfilelog
```

But if you've any other queries after your DELETE statement and it threw error and never reached ROLLBACK statment in that case your rows are gone.

You better use TRY..CATCH and put your ROLLBACK in CATCH. It will always rollback if there's any error.

Answer (score 0):

you can use safe and easy code for run 100% (run all line of query) or no run any off them

- |query 1| = like insert into or select or ...
- |count of lines| = number off query

```csharp
    DECLARE @rowcount int  set @rowcount = 0 ; 
    BEGIN TRANSACTION [Tran1]
    BEGIN TRY 
     <Query 1> ; set @rowcount = (@rowcount + @@ROWCOUNT); 
     <Query 2> ; set @rowcount = (@rowcount + @@ROWCOUNT); 
    ...
    IF @rowcount =  <count of lines>
      COMMIT TRANSACTION[Tran1]
    ELSE
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION[Tran1]
    END TRY
      BEGIN CATCH
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION[Tran1]
    END CATCH
```

for example this code run 2 insert into line query but or run all of him or no run anything and ROLLBACK

```csharp
    DECLARE @rowcount int  set @rowcount = 0 ; 
    BEGIN TRANSACTION [Tran1]
    BEGIN TRY 
     insert into [database].[dbo].[tbl1] (fld1) values('1') ;
        set @rowcount = (@rowcount + @@ROWCOUNT); 
     insert into [database].[dbo].[tbl2] (fld1) values('2') ;
        set @rowcount = (@rowcount + @@ROWCOUNT); 

    IF @rowcount =  2
      COMMIT TRANSACTION[Tran1]
    ELSE
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION[Tran1]
    END TRY
      BEGIN CATCH
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION[Tran1]
    END CATCH
```